# parallel execution is not improving performance in Java-webapp

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, parallel-processing, fileutils

I have to download a bunch of files from a URL using Apache Commons -FileUtils.copyURLToFile in a Java web application through which multiple users accessing the webapp can download multiple files  , tried in two ways

1. sequential download

   for(each url in array)
   FileUtils.copyURLToFile
2. parallel execution using ThreadPoolExecutor

   for(each url in array)
   Executors.submit(downloader)
   fn->downloader
   FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Both of them seems to yield same performance and ThreadPoolExecutor actually performing worse in case there is more number of users accessing the application (my guess-because of thread pool management, thread launch delays etc.).

The tomcat server is running on quad core processor, why there is no performance gain in parallel execution?

Comment: Check if your pool is big enough: pool_size >= users * files_per_user

Comment: Check that your network connection is not being saturated.  If you're I/O bound on the network, adding threads won't improve things.

Comment: @Konstantin Pavlov How to correctly set the pool size? users and the files per user download is variable.

Comment: @jim-garrison -Not sure if FileUtils.copyURLToFile is I/O bound on network. Can I know the reason why threads won't be useful for these?

Comment: If your network is saturated, it means all available bandwidth is being used.  Attempting to send more data will not improve things.

Comment: Use it to create an executor with a fixed size thread pool http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-

Comment: @jim-garrison The server for getting the pdf is running locally to the web app tomcat server.I will run a saturation test to know more.

Comment: @Konstantin Pavlov-I have used newCachedThreadPool instead of a fixed size thread pool docs. I will try with fixed size as well.

Comment: I tried fixed size thread pool did not help! Seems network bandwidth is also fine as the url to download is hosted locally to the tomcat.

Comment: If everything is on fast local network, and network is not saturated, it is likely the harddisk of the server or the client that is saturated. Starting multiple threads will *worsen* performance by making the harddisk schizophrenic, i.e. the disk arm is trying to read/write multiple places on the disk, wasting time jumping around, rather than just pumping data from/to the disk. If you're on Windows, run the Windows Performance Monitor to see disk activity, or just watch the disk light blink on the front of the computer. If lit (i.e. not blinking), disk is saturated.

Comment: @Andreas- I disk performance is also pretty good, the disc usage % comes around 7-8%.

Comment: Check if you have any threads blocked with jvisualvm.